# Spring boot executable jar unable to load jsp file?

Tags: spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot application development. I refer [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging) to develop my first Spring Boot application.

Here is my **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>SpringBoot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-web-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-boot-web-jsp</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Web JSP Example</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSTL for JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Optional, test for static content, bootstrap CSS-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In **Eclipse STS** the project structure looks like following:-

[image]

Now if I run my application using IDE then everything works fine. Or if I build using apache-maven (`mvn clean package`) and run through cmd (`java -jer target/spring-boot-web-jsp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`) also works fine. It ended with opening the following web page:-

[image]

But my understanding from [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-install) also says if I double click on the executable `spring-boot-web-jsp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` should also open above web page.

[image]

Is my understanding wrong or I am doning something wrong?

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations for the limitations on using JSPs with Spring Boot.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out that. So, does that means we can't develop GUI like application using Spring-Boot? If so then it's the worst conclusion for a spring boot app.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to do so. Just create a war instead of a jar or use a different view technology like Thymeleaf.

Comment: Yes yes you are right indeed. But I am getting exception while doing so using war that contains JSP and I know nothing about Thymeleaf.

Comment: Your question is about creating a `jar` not a `war`. Packaging is set to `jar` not `war`

Comment: Yeah, but as you mention using `jar` it's not possible to run GUI application. That's why I change the `pom.xml` to `war` type packaging and `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` scope to `provided`. But when I am deploying the `war` file in my tomcat server and accessing it using `http://localhost:8081/spring-boot-web-jsp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/` getting exception `HTTP Status 404 - /spring-boot-web-jsp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/`. Why?

Comment: do you have a mapping for `/`

Comment: Yes, I do. `@RequestMapping("/")` at the method level. No other mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As M.Deinum pointed out in comments, it's not possible to develop a web application whose view technology is JSP and build as an executable jar. In order to do so either, you have to change the view technology or change build type to war.